# Postfix transport old local domain to new Exchagne

Tags: postfix, exchange, dovecot

I have Postifix with Dovecot for more domain a.com b.com c.cz maindomain.com etc. I created new Exchagne server for domain maindomain.com and when I change MX for maindomain.com everything works good for delivering from Internet to maindomain.com in Exchange, but from another my domain in Postfix server (a.com b.com c.cz), where was maindomain.com when I send e-mail from a.com or b.com or c.cz then mail is deliver to old mail box in Postfix server not to the Exchange.

Is it possible only add this to transport file in postfix:

`maindomain.com  smtp:[excahnge.domain.com]`

Or I must do something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the file is specified in the [`transport_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) parameter it works as a [transport](http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html) table and overrides the default `transport:nexthop` selection that is built into Postfix. Therefore, adding that line should be sufficient.

As the transport table is most likely a `hash:` Berkeley DB, remember to use [`postmap`](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html) for it.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I wasn't sure if it is sufficient. In default, postfix check own domains and in next step check MX for domain for which hasn't found local. In my case this is wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that postfix does not treat those emails as local: maindomain.com should not be listed as [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination). Then if postfix could not send the email (e.g. you need to use the internal IPs instead of the public MX) you would need to add it to the transport (and as Esa mentions above, remember to update the database with [`postmap`](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html).

Comment: Actually, `transport_maps` overrides even the local delivery. That's especially useful when some of the users are local and some are external.